# Bluebeam or Adobe SaveAs via Submit button using JS

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, microsoft-forms

I am trying to see if anyone knows of a workaround to do a save-as using a submit button within a PDF. I have a working version using Trusted functions in Adobe, but for our needs would like to avoid having our end-users from placing  .js files in the trusted location on their machines.

The reason I am trying to do a save-as is to simply rename the output file with the date and username and place the files in a centralized location for data collection.

We are aware of using Adobe to distribute and receive responses from end-users... but as mentioned above we are using both platforms, and also have some DirectX issues.

I have also created the same Form in Microsoft Forms and I personally feel like this may be our best option in rolling this out, but before we wrote anything off, I figured I would try and see if there are any other options using JS and PDF's.